# Custom music player using youtube, sound cloud, and mp3 streaming

Tags: flash, actionscript, youtube, streaming, soundcloud

Any ideas on how to create a custom player that would stream a list of youtube videos along with soundcloud, and MP3 similar to the one on fizy.com

I know that this might seem like quite a general question but any direction on how to accomplish this and whether it should be done using flash and Youtube API, and sound cloud API or whether it should be done with some sort of flash audio ripping way.

ANy guidance on how to do this would be really appreciated

Comment: fizy.com used to use 15+ public music sources but had to stop them due to copyright and licensing issues. You should be careful about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://mycloudplayers.com/ysmPlayer.html
it's not a flash/flax app, just javascript/jquery, with soundcloud & youtube apis, and their native embed players.
mixcloud api and official.fm api are also included, but their players does not trigger events like playStatusChanged on similar, so continuous play cannot be done for this engines.

anyway, you can uncheck the checkboxes and search and play only on soundcloud and youtube.
cheers.